# Creating a slider/slideshow with information from my database

Tags: javascript, php, slider

I have tried creating a sort of slider with dynamic information from my db, but I don't know how to sort out that there may be various information available from topic to topic.

What I am looking for is a "slide" to display the following content:

- "Step 1" (and so on as for so many steps provided by the form)
- "Short description" (that text is relevant to what step is showing
- "Next step/last step button" (so it is possible to navigate the
  information.

Hoping that someone could please help me find a good solution :)

KG
Cathrine :)

Comment: Please go read [ask], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Show us code, please. What is your database system? PLSQL, TSQL, MariaDB? I can only guess. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26224019).